# how to add value from one combo box to another combo box

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a combo box with some list of values .After selecting from the list I need to add the rest of the values in the combo box to another combo box .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand you correctly, this code will help you

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If you need, clear second combo box from old values before you copy
        //comboBox2.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item != comboBox1.SelectedItem)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);

                //If you need to remove item that were copied to second combo box, from the first
                //comboBox1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```